# Getting the "base URL" of a URL

Tags: perl, url

In my application I need to get the base URL of any URL. Up until now I've been getting it like so:

```
$resp->base;
```

Where `$resp` is a [`HTTP::Response`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.03/lib/HTTP/Response.pm) object. However, now I need to know the base of URLs *without* actually requesting them and getting an `HTTP::Response` object back. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find the the absolute url to which "`.`" expands, relative to the url you have. [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) can do that.

```
$ perl -MURI -E'say URI->new_abs(".", $_) for @ARGV' \
   'http://www.example.org/dir/' \
   'http://www.example.org/dir/file.html' \
   'http://www.example.org/dir/file.cgi?foo=bar'
http://www.example.org/dir/
http://www.example.org/dir/
http://www.example.org/dir/
```

Comment: It returns a URI object, but URI objects are automatically stringified to the uri they represent when needed. You can also stringify it explicitly using `->as_string`

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by the `HTTP::Response->base` method is a URL obtained from the HTTP response message that specifies how to resolve relative URLs that appear in the content of the message. If the message doesn't specify such a value then the URL used to request the message is used instead.

If you want the URL that would come from an `HTTP::Response` assuming there was no information to the contrary in the response then just use the URL as it is. It will work fine as a base URL.

There is no single base for an arbitrary URL. A base URL is an absolute URL that is used to resolve relative URLS, and can have any number of path steps.

For instance,

```
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/click_online/9735140.stm
```

can be expressed as

```
9735140.stm
```

relative to base URL

```
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/click_online/
```

or as

```
1/hi/programmes/click_online/9735140.stm
```

relative to base URL

```
http://news.bbc.co.uk/
```

or, of course, the path can be divided between the base and relative URL at any point.

You don't say what it is you want to use the value for. The solution you have chosen simply strips off the last element of the path-component of the URL that isn't followed by a slash, so for the URL

```
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/click_online
```

it returns

```
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/
```

but for

```
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/click_online/
```

it returns the same value

```
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/click_online/
```

If that is the behaviour you want then all is well, but I wouldn't describe it as "taking the base URL".